# Mobile web: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch conflicts with position:fixed

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, css-position

I use `position: fixed` to create a fixed top navigation menu on my mobile web application.

After adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`, the scrolling works smoothly. However, the top menu disappears during scrolling. It shows only after the scrolling stops.

I have searched many solutions, such as [CSS3 property webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808110/css3-property-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch-error) and [iOS5 Images disappear when scrolling with webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110580/ios5-images-disappear-when-scrolling-with-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch/8275972#8275972). However, the given solutions are not working for me. Please check out this example: http://jsbin.com/woxuwihuzu/12/ (visited from iPhone 5c Chrome/Firefox).

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After two days struggling, I found this post saves me: [100% screen height css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357818/100-screen-height-css).

I have to limit the height of my content area to be the same height of the screen. Please find the working demo here: http://jsbin.com/tubaqaqumi/3/ (visit from a real phone; a Chrome simulator doesn't tell the difference).

Comment: So what's the solution if you want the content area to be taller than the height of the screen?